# take values between spaces and dot

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

i have these kind of strings,

```
1. "Drs. H. Ahmad Malik S.Kom S.E S.pd"
2. "H. Ahmad Abdul Malik S.Kom S.E S.pd"
```

Expected output :

```
1. Ahmad Malik
2. Ahmad Abdul Malik
```

can anyone help me to solve it, i've try with substring, patindex but always did not get the expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated for new information

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int,Name varchar(100))
Insert Into @YourTable values
(4,'Drs. H. Ahmad Malik A. N. S.Kom S.E S.pd'),
(1,'Drs. H. Ahmad Malik S.Kom S.E S.pd'),
(2,'H. Ahmad Abdul Malik S.Kom S.E S.pd'),
(3,'Drs. H. Ahmad Malik S.Kom S.E S.pd')

Select A.*
      ,C.*
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (Select * From [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse](A.Name,'S.Kom') Where RetSeq=1) B
 Cross Apply (
              Select NewString = Stuff((Select  ' ' +RetVal 
                                        From (
                                              Select *,Excl=min(Flag) over (Order By RetSeq)
                                               From (Select *,Flag=case when charindex('.',RetVal)>0 then 1 else 0 end From [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse](B.RetVal,' ') ) C1
                                             ) C2
                                        Where Excl=0
                                        Order by RetSeq
                                        For XML Path ('')),1,1,'')
             ) C
```

**Returns**

```
ID  Name                                        NewString
1   Drs. H. Ahmad Malik S.Kom S.E S.pd          Ahmad Malik
2   H. Ahmad Abdul Malik S.Kom S.E S.pd         Ahmad Abdul Malik
3   Drs. H. Ahmad Malik S.Kom S.E S.pd          Ahmad Malik
4   Drs. H. Ahmad Malik A. N. S.Kom S.E S.pd    Ahmad Malik A. N.   << Notice A. N.
```

Comment: THX a lot john, I Appreciate it a lot. thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Just about any parse/split function would do the trick.

**Option 1 With a Parse/Split Function**

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int,Name varchar(100))
Insert Into @YourTable values
(1,'Drs. H. Ahmad Malik S.Kom S.E S.pd'),
(2,'H. Ahmad Abdul Malik S.Kom S.E S.pd')

Select A.*
      ,B.*
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
              Select NewString = Stuff((Select  ' ' +RetVal 
                From [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse](A.Name,' ') 
                Where RetVal Not Like '%.%'
             Order by RetSeq
             For XML Path ('')),1,1,'')
  ) B
```

**Option 2 Without a Parse/Split Function**

```
Select A.*
      ,B.*
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
              Select NewString = Stuff((Select  ' ' +RetVal 
                From (
                        Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null))
                              ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
                        From  (Select x = Cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(A.Name,' ','§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
                        Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
                     ) B1
                Where RetVal Not Like '%.%'
             Order by RetSeq
             For XML Path ('')),1,1,'')
  ) B
```

**Both Return**

```
ID  Name                                  NewString
1   Drs. H. Ahmad Malik S.Kom S.E S.pd    Ahmad Malik 
2   H. Ahmad Abdul Malik S.Kom S.E S.pd   Ahmad Abdul Malik
```

**The UDF if Interested**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse] (@String varchar(max),@Delimiter varchar(25))
Returns Table 
As
Return (  
    with   cte1(N)   As (Select 1 From (Values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) N(N)),
           cte2(N)   As (Select Top (IsNull(DataLength(@String),0)) Row_Number() over (Order By (Select NULL)) From (Select N=1 From cte1 a,cte1 b,cte1 c,cte1 d) A ),
           cte3(N)   As (Select 1 Union All Select t.N+DataLength(@Delimiter) From cte2 t Where Substring(@String,t.N,DataLength(@Delimiter)) = @Delimiter),
           cte4(N,L) As (Select S.N,IsNull(NullIf(CharIndex(@Delimiter,@String,s.N),0)-S.N,8000) From cte3 S)

    Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By A.N)
          ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(Substring(@String, A.N, A.L)))
    From   cte4 A
);
--Orginal Source http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/
--Much faster than str-Parse, but limited to 8K
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse-8K]('Dog,Cat,House,Car',',')
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse-8K]('John||Cappelletti||was||here','||')
```

Comment: i forgot to add, **"Drs. H. Ahmad Malik S.Kom S.E S.pd"** it works, but if its **"Drs. H. Ahmad Malik A. N. S.Kom S.E S.pd"**  it's not work. expected the results **Ahmad Malik A. N. the A. N.** its part of his name, not his degree.

Comment: @MuhammadIdrus I'll noodle it a bit more

Comment: in my country if some one goes to haj they get the **H. His Name** tittle in front of his name. if they graduate bachelor, they got a degree behind their name, such as **S.KOM, S.pd** and so on. his name is **abdul malik abdul karim**, he always write down his name **abdul malik A. K.** i want to strip the front and back degree but keep his name.

Comment: @MuhammadIdrus That helps.  Give me a few minutes to work it out

Comment: @MuhammadIdrus Didn't forget about you.  Just tuning the logic switch

Comment: @MuhammadIdrus Added a second answer